# how to make onDraw drawing smoother

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview, smoothing, ondraw

I am moving an image from top of the screen till it reaches the bottom of the screen to give it a dropping pin like effect. It is working fine but the problem is with the animating  effects. I want this to be as smooth as possible but I can easily find jerks in this dropping effect.

I have used a Surfaceview and a thread to achieve this. Thread keeps on updating the image's position by one pixel and call Surfaceview's onDraw(canvas) method where the image with updated coordinates gets drawn.

Here is some code snippet. First the drawing thread that keeps on updating my image coordinates by some pixels.

```
while(mRun){
    canvas = null;
    try{
        canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        //increment the coordinate by 5 pixels
            image.getCoordinate.setX(image.getCoordinate.getX + 5);
            image.getCoordinate.setY(image.getCoordinate.getY + 5);

        synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {

            //call onDraw method to update position on canvas
            mPanel.onDraw(canvas);
        }

    }finally{
        if(canvas != null){
            mPanel.getSurfaceHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

Then the onDraw method from my SurfaceView class that draws the updated image on the canvas :

```
canvas.drawBitmap(image, image.getCoordinate().getX(),image.getCoordinate().getY(), null);
```

This seems to be simple but there are jerks and I am looking for some ways to avoid these jerks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post some code of how your drawing looks. Generally it is better to check how much time has passed since the last update, and calculate an offset rather than having a set offset (such as one pixel). This way you can get a consistent motion even if your drawing would take longer than expected.

Comment: Hi, I have update my post with some code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for that, it makes it a bit easier to understand what you are doing, could you please also post the rest of the `onDraw()` method, just in case there is anything that could lower the performance in there?

Comment: @Jave: That's it in my onDraw method.

Comment: Just try it on real device. It will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Saurabh Pareek : Thanks buddy for your nice suggestion.

I was testing the same on the emulator. But when I tried to run the same on a Device, it worked fine. No jerk and pretty nice animation.